# Проблема со ссылками

Tags: css

Итак, у меня есть следующий кусок кода в таблице стилей:

```
.links a:active, a:visited, a:link { 
display:block; 
background-color:#0C0C0B; 
margin-bottom:3px; 
border:#656564 1px solid; 
text-decoration:none; 
color:#428AFF; 
padding:3px
;
```

Но дело в том, что под это описание попали исключительно все ссылки на сайте, а не только те, которые находятся внутри `<div class = "links"></div>`. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.links a:active, .links a:visited, .links a:link {
  display:block; 
  background-color:#0C0C0B; 
  margin-bottom:3px; 
  border:#656564 1px solid; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:#428AFF; 
  padding:3px
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.